# Do i need to first request a real Ad to get the Device ID from the logcat so i can add a testdevice?

Tags: android, admob

In the documentation it says you should add a test device this way.

But to get this ID from the logcat do i have to first Request a real ad? Isn't that against their own policy to request real ads?

> **Add your test device**
>
> Load your ads-integrated app and make an ad request. Check the logcat
> output for a message that looks like the one
> below, which shows you your device ID and how to add it as a test
> device:
>
> I/Ads: Use
> AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231") to
> get test ads on this device."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a) test ad units, which one can use and b) it knows when it is running in debug mode.

This message likely shows in the log before showing any ad unit, but when instancing the client.

Comment: I picked the second option in the documentation (Use your own ad unit and enable test devices), but what about testing a release version of the app?

Comment: You should only test release builds on devices with a matching test-device hash (for debug builds and test ads this is merely useless, but in release builds it doesn't count invalid clicks then).